# How long does Instagram API access tokens last?

Tags: php, instagram, instagram-api

I would like to know how long Instagram API access tokens last? It's not very clear how long they last on their documentation and every PHP package that uses the Instagram API and they all just expect a static access token (along with the client ID and secret) which indicates to me it doesn't change very much.

I am trying to display an Instagram feed on a website, and would like to know if I need to build extra code to periodically check the access token still works or if this is negligible.

Comment: Yes, you do need to check that the token is still valid. There is no set time frame. A token being mandatory is a relatively recent update, so many php packages may well just not have updated (or maybe the author just wants you to get the paid version, e.g. with WordPress plugins)

Comment: Two cases I know the token used to expire for Instagram are: 1. When user changes password. 2. When security check-point is reached for the account that is when the site detects some malicious activity with account login attempt. (there can be other cases - but there is no fixed expire time for Instagram tokens)

Comment: thanks @enator, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/

> Access tokens may expire at any time in the future.

+

> Even though our access tokens do not specify an expiration time, your
>   app should handle the case that either the user revokes access, or
>   Instagram expires the token after some period of time. If the token is
>   no longer valid, API responses will contain an
>   “error_type=OAuthAccessTokenException”. In this case you will need to
>   re-authenticate the user to obtain a new valid token. In other words:
>   do not assume your access_token is valid forever.